# How can I sign a JWT with RS256 using PS256 private key in node.js

Tags: node.js, jwt, openssl, rsa, jose

I have the following keys created with openssl (the algorithms etc. are
specified by the counterpart):

```bash
openssl req -newkey rsa-pss -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

I have the following working Java code:

```java
private static String createJwtToken() {
    try {
        Path privateKeyPath = Path.of("/Users/abc/bzstcerts/key.pem");
        Path publicKeyPath = Path.of("/Users/abc/bzstcerts/pubkey.pem");

        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)readPrivateKey(privateKeyPath);
        RSAPublicKey publicKey =(RSAPublicKey) readPublicKey(publicKeyPath);

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256( publicKey,  privateKey);

        return JWT.create()
                .withIssuer("iss")
                .withSubject("subject")
                .withAudience("audience")
                .withIssuedAt(new Date())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 60 * 1000L)))
                .withJWTId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60 * 1000L))
                .sign(algorithm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
 }

private static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(Path privateKeyPath) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyPath);
    keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyBytes);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
    return keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
}

private static PublicKey readPublicKey(Path publicKeyPath) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(publicKeyPath);
    keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyBytes);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

Here the private and public keys are loaded using RSASSA-PSS and casted to RSAPrivateKey and RSAPublicKey respectively.

I try to achieve the same with jose in node but I have no success.

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as jose from 'jose'
import * as uuid from 'uuid'
import path from 'node:path'

const jwtUuid = uuid.v4()
const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
const expirationTime = currentTime + 300
const notValidBeforeTime = currentTime - 60
const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID
const audienceUrl = process.env.AUDIENCE_URL

const getSignedJWTToken = async () => {
    const signOptions: jose.JWTPayload = {
        iss: clientId,
        sub: clientId,
        aud: audienceUrl,
        iat: currentTime,
        exp: expirationTime,
        jti: jwtUuid,
        nbf: notValidBeforeTime,
    }
    const privateKey = await getPrivateKey()

    const signedJwt = await new jose.SignJWT(signOptions)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'PS256' })
        .setIssuer(clientId)
        .setSubject(clientId)
        .setAudience(audienceUrl)
        .setIssuedAt(currentTime)
        .setExpirationTime(expirationTime)
        .setJti(jwtUuid)
        .setNotBefore(notValidBeforeTime)
        .sign(privateKey)
    console.log(`\nsignedJwt in generateRequestToken:\n${signedJwt}`)
    return signedJwt
}

const certPath = path.resolve('./assets/cert')
const privateKeyName = 'key.pem'
const getPrivateKey = async () => {
    const privateKeyPath = `${certPath}/${privateKeyName}`
    const privateKeyString = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf-8')
    return await jose.importPKCS8(privateKeyString, 'PS256')
}

const publicKeyName = 'pubkey.pem'
const getPublicKey = async () => {
    const publicKeyPath = `${certPath}/${publicKeyName}`
    const publicKeyString = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyPath, 'utf-8')
    console.log(`\npublicKeyString from readFileSync:\n${publicKeyString}`)
    return await jose.importSPKI(publicKeyString, 'PS256')
}
```

I can load the keys and sign the jwt using PS256 algorithm, but I can't load the keys with PS256 algorithm, convert them to RS256 algorithm and sign the jwt. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I can load the keys and sign the jwt using PS256 algorithm, but I can't load the keys with PS256 algorithm, convert them to RS256 algorithm and sign the jwt. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

> Here the private and public keys are loaded using RSASSA-PSS and casted to RSAPrivateKey and RSAPublicKey respectively.

You've generated an RSASSA-PSS key, it cannot be used for RS256, at least not in Node.js, there's no manipulation in the crypto module you could do to drop/change the key's parameters.

If you want a key that's usable for both RS256 and PS256 in Node.js use this

```
openssl req -newkey rsa -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I would like to adapt the certificate and the keys accordingly. Unfortunately, I am dependent on the API of the German Ministry of Finance at this point. Unfortunately, I have to implement the solution in Java and cannot (yet) use jose in this case. Best!

Answer (score 0):

i am working on a very similar problem. The German Ministry of Finance has the requirement that the certificate has to have rsa-pss. But every implementation of generating JWT has a problem using such a key generated with rsa-pss to sign. It may validate locally but it never does on jwt.io or at the API.
Generally you can sign with openssl using a command like:
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign /path/to/key.pem
And it works if you use a certificate that wasn't created with "rsa-pss", jwt.io says they are valid, but not having rsa-pss is not an option here.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Yes, we went through a number of options and built our own validation using Java. Signing also worked best with Java. As you have already mentioned, all online tools are not reliable in this situation.

Comment: If you could point me to anything useful regarding the validation i would be very grateful. Did you find out what all the tools are doing wrong?